# how to replace array data in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I need to replace some data in an array with new ones from another array. I performed a loop in which I removed words from certain values ​​to lowercase. Now I want to update the data, but for some reason it does not update.

```
const initialState = {
    list: []
};


case Constants.dataNodes.success: {
            const newState = { ...state };

            newState.list = [...newState.list, ...action.payload];


            const filterFQDN = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < newState.list.length; i++) {
                filterFQDN.push(newState.list[i].fqdn.toLowerCase());
            }

            for (let a = 0; a < newState.list.length; a++) {
                for (let b = 0; b < filterFQDN.length; b++) {
                    if (filterFQDN[b] === newState.list[a]) {
                        return newState.list = [...newState.list[a].fqdn, ...filterFQDN[b]];
                    }
                }
            }
          
        }
```

Comment: I guess what's throwing me off is the return in the double-nested for-loop, you seem to be missing a return. Is that the intended value you want returned in the reducer? or are you trying to iterate over the data more and update more elements? Can you be a bit more explicit in what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: there are objects in the newState.list array with fqdn value which I need to lowercase. in a loop, I first take all the values ​​and store them in lowercase into a new array. after I want to replace the values ​​from the new array in the state

Comment: So you simply want to copy the old array, add data, and lowercase all the elements' `fqdn` property?

Comment: the original goal is to lowercase the elements of fqdn. Yes, I want to replace the state with new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shallow copy existing state, then shallow copy the existing state.list into a new array and append the payload to the end. Map this new array to another array where you can `toLowerCase()` the `fqdn` property.

```
case Constants.dataNodes.success: {
  const newState = {
    ...state,
    list: [...state.list, ...action.payload].map((el) => ({
      ...el,
      fqdn: el.fqdn.toLowerCase()
    }))
  };
}
```

Since you start with an empty array you should only need to `toLowerCase` the new data coming in though, so you can map the payload instead of the entire state array each time.

```
case Constants.dataNodes.success: {
  const newState = {
    ...state,
    list: [
      ...state.list,
      ...action.payload.map((el) => ({
        ...el,
        fqdn: el.fqdn.toLowerCase()
      }))
    ]
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this case, the register changes and is displayed correctly, but when searching, it sees only if you enter in the top.